# How to reset MediaPlayer java in Android app?

Tags: java, android, media

I have some buttons to play sound in app and I want to reset Media Player after the sound will be played. Can I get some advice how to do this if I have code like that?

```
final MediaPlayer Sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.somesound);
final Button play_Sound1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_Sound1);

play_Sound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
            Sound1.start();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a completion listener. Add the code below

```
sound1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            sound1.reset();
        }

        });
```

Comment: it works but I cant back and play sound1 after reset :/

Comment: I didn't' understand correctly what you want but If you want to replay the sound1 then you don't need to reset it. just use `sound1.start()` again.

Comment: After plays some sounds the next sounds didn't play so I want to reset the earlier sounds to play the next. But when after that I back to the 1st sound it not playing. So I play 1st sound, 2 sound, 3 sound (after that reset), play 4 sound (works properly after reset 3), back to 3 (not work).

Comment: So you want to play multiple sounds one by one right?

Answer (score 0):

If the sound plays to completion, the MediaPlayer will be in the `PlaybackCompleted` state. If you call `start()` in this state, the sound will play from the beginning.

If you need to stop and restart while the sound is playing you can do this:

```
mediaPlayer.pause()
mediaPlayer.seekTo(0)
mediaPlayer.start()
```

You can also do:

```
mediaPlayer.stop()
mediaPlayer.prepare()
mediaPlayer.start()
```

You should take a look at the MediaPlayer state diagram here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html